# PL/SQL: Calling a procedure recursively

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I may be way off with this, but I'm trying to write a procedure that inserts all the ancestors of a given child into a new table. Here's what I have:

```
create or replace procedure ancestors(childIn IN varchar2)
is
begin
insert into AncestorTable(Parent)
select Parent from Family
where Child=childIn;
ancestors(Parent);
end;
/
```

I know the `ancestors(Parent)`is way off but I was wondering if there's an easy way to do this without going into cursors. If I need a cursor, could I get some direction on how to do that? Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a [hierarchical query](http://www.orafaq.com/node/2038).

Something like

```
select Parent 
  from Family
 start with Child=childIn
connect by prior Parent = Child;
```

Here's an [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8b227/2)

This way you can make a single insert and you dont need recursion.

```
insert into AncestorTable(Parent)
(select Parent 
   from Family
 start with Child=childIn
  connect by prior Parent = Child);
```